# Get original document field as part of aggregate result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am wanting to get all of the document fields in my aggregate results but as soon as I use $group they are gone. Using $project allows me to readd whatever fields I have defined in $group but no luck on getting the other fields:

```
var doc = {
  _id: '123',
  name: 'Bob',
  comments: [],
  attendances: [{
    answer: 'yes'
  }, { 
   answer: 'no'
  }]       
}

aggregate({
    $unwind: '$attendances'
  }, {
    $match: {
      "attendances.answer": { $ne:"no" }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    attendances: { $sum: 1 },
    comments: {  $sum: { $size: { $ifNull: [ "$comments", [] ] }}}
  } 
}, {
  $project: {
    comments: 1,
  }
}
```

This results in:

```
[{
  _id: 5317b771b6504bd4a32395be,
  comments: 12 
},{
  _id: 53349213cb41af00009a94d0,
  comments: 0 
}]
```

How do I get 'name' in there? I have tried adding to $group as:

```
name: '$name'
```

as well as in $project:

```
name: 1
```

But neither will work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't project fields that are removed during the `$group` operation.

Since you are grouping by the original document `_id` and there will only be one `name` value, you can preserve the `name` field using [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/):

```
db.sample.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        comments: {  $sum: { $size: { $ifNull: [ "$comments", [] ] }}},
        name: { $first: "$name" }
    }}
)
```

Example output would be:
    { "_id" : "123", "comments" : 0, "name" : "Bob" }

If you are grouping by criteria where there could be multiple values to preserve, you should either [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to an array in the `$group` or use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) if you only want unique names.

#### Projecting all the fields

If you are using MongoDB 2.6 and want to get *all* of the original document fields (not just `name`) without listing them individually you can use the aggregation variable [`$$ROOT`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) in place of a specific field name.

Comment: No way to just get name as a string?

Comment: @yashua: A `$group` aggregation combines values from multiple documents, so you have to do something with multiple name fields. You could use `$first` to get the first name in the list as a string, but I think what you're after is a just a `$project` as suggested by JohnnyHK. Is your actual use case more complicated than what is posted in the question description?

Comment: @yashua: Updated my answer based on your revised question. You can use `$first` to get `name` as a string rather than an array, since you are grouping on the original document `_id`.

Comment: How would I use $$ROOT to get all fields? That is ultimately what I want. I am able to do this: `original: { $push: "$$ROOT" }` but that places everything in an object rather than root level

Comment: @Yashua: Your usage is correct - that is how `$$ROOT` works as at MongoDB 2.6. You'll get all the original fields in a subdocument, rather than having those merged at the root level. If you want to keep the fields at the root level you will have to specify them individually. A relevant feature suggestion you should watch/upvote is [SERVER-5781: Allow adding fields to input objects in $project operation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5781).